# TeXstudio for macOS doesn't show PDF in embedded viewer

Tags: pdf, texstudio

If I close the internal PDF viewer on the right panel in TeXstudio, after a rebuild I can't see the generated PDF document anymore. Before it has been working without any sort of problem. I tried to click on the top menu **View** and select the PDF view option but nothing happened.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Did you try to turn it off and on again?

Comment: So is the window not shown or is it visible but grayed out (without PDF content)? If the latter is the case, there may be a tex error, which should be displayed when compiling.

Comment: can you still see the PDF in an external viewer?

Comment: turn it off and again without success, the window is neither visible, and yes, the pdf file is present with the exact same name of the tex main document and I can open it with another program

Comment: @ocram can you retypedet the document?

Comment: Sorry @HerbSchulz, what do you mean with "retypedet" the document?

Comment: @ocram Sorry, that should be retypeset the document.

Answer (score 5):

I click on **Tools**>**Commands**>**View PDF** and it worked!

Comment: One year later ... same problem (on macOS) - I have to do this manually first time I view a new PDF file. If I don't change the file I am compiling, it updates the embedded viewer. Is there a better solution?